# How do I use aioschedule in cog class in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a cog which is ment to handel events and loops. I am using aioschedule to run ping every minute as a test if the aioschedule works. But now the problem is that when I put it inside the class it asks for self but when i give self it gives an error.pls help with this

```
import discord
import os
import asyncio
import time
from discord.ext import commands,tasks
import aioschedule as schedule


class Events(commands.Cog):

  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

  async def bot_test_clear(self):
    channel_bot_test = self.client.get_channel(os.getenv('bot-test-text'))
    messages = await channel_bot_test.history(limit=100).flatten()

    if not messages:
      return
    
    embed = discord.Embed(description='It has been 1 hour, clearing chats...', color=0xff0000)
    await channel_bot_test.send(embed=embed)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await channel_bot_test.purge(limit=None)  

  
  async def ping(self):
    self.client.send("pong")

  schedule.every(5).seconds.do(ping)

  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_ready(self):
    self.bot_text_clear.start()

    print(f'{self.client.user} is now online')


def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(Events(client))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
while True:
  loop.run_until_complete(schedule.run_pending())
  time.sleep(0.1)
```

[img of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erp1H.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I answered your earlier question and suggested you use aioschedule so I will show you how I use it.

```
def _run_scheduler(self):
    """ Create the scheduler task. """

    async def _run_scheduler():
        self._scheduler_running = True

        print("Created 'Scheduler' task")

        while self._scheduler_running:
            await aioschedule.run_pending()

            await asyncio.sleep(0.25)

    if not self._scheduler_running:
        asyncio.create_task(_run_scheduler())
```

The above method is attached to my bot, and is called once when the bot is created. The above code will process all the jobs you schedule. I use `create_task` so I can call the method from a non-async method.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_startup(self):

    aioschedule.every().monday.at("21:15").do(self.announce_winners)

    aioschedule.every().day.at("21:30").do(self.start_quiz)
```

I add jobs, which are then processed in that event loop in the earlier code block. I use `on_startup` (a custom event) which is called after `on_ready` since `on_ready` can be called multiple times if the bot disconnects (stop duplicate jobs)

Your error (which should be text, not an image) is due to `schedule.every(5).seconds.do(ping)` being called and it is expecting `self` which you do not give it.

Comment: it is not calling the `on_startup` function how to solve that

Comment: its a custom event, so you will need to dispatch it yourself or use on_ready